# A (probably easy) question about exchanging the order of this double sum

Tags: summation

I would like to exchange the order of the following:

$\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}\sum_{r=1}^{2k}$ (stuff).

I feel like it should be easy, but so far I am only able to produce

$\sum_{r=1}^{2(i-1)}\sum_{k=??}^{??}$ (stuff).

In particular, I don't see how to reconcile the inequalities $1 \leq r\leq 2k\,$ and $1 \leq k \leq i-1$\, without introducing half integers into the sum.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sum should be $$\sum_{k=\lceil \frac r2\rceil}^{i-1}$$
$k$ is always at least $\frac r2$ and ranges up to $i-1$

Comment: I think $k$ starts from $[\frac r 2]$ if $r$ is even and $[\frac r 2]+1$ if $r$ is odd.

Comment: @Kavi That's exactly what $\lceil{r\over2}\rceil$ means.

Comment: I see. I didn't know this. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is clear, thanks.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy:  those brackets represent the ceiling function-you round up to the next integer.  Upside down ones are the floor, where you round down.

Comment: Sorry about asking a new question here, but it's so related that I can't justify making a seperate topic:

Did I compute this exchange correctly?  

$$\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}\sum_{n=1}^{i-1-k}\sum_{s=1}^{2n} a_{kns} = \sum_{s=1}^{2(i-2)}\sum_{k=1}^{i-1-\lceil s/2 \rceil}\sum_{n=\lceil s/2 \rceil}^{i-1-k} a_{kns}$$

Comment: It looks good, but it can be confusing

Comment: Thank you for checking!  Out of curiosity, what would you do to make it less confusing?